# LoginView and NavigationDrawerController

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

sorry if this question was asked already, but I didn't find an answer.

I'm new to ios development and I already have an android application with an LoginActivity which redirects to an NavigationDrawer Activity when the login is successful.

Now I want to create the same functions for my IOS App.
Does an IOS solution already exist for this case, or are there any examples?

Best regards,

Patrick

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/login-signup-parse-swift/ follow this link ,you will get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement navigation drawer in iOS there are so many libraries available one of the good library with so many customization is [LGSideMenuController](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController)

Very easy to use

For pod installation

```
pod 'LGSideMenuController'
```

To import into our viewcontroller

```
import LGSideMenuController
```

Further implementaions

```
let rootViewController = UIViewController()
let leftViewController = UITableViewController()
let rightViewController = UITableViewController()

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)

let sideMenuController = LGSideMenuController(rootViewController: navigationController,
                                              leftViewController: leftViewController,
                                             rightViewController: rightViewController)

sideMenuController.leftViewWidth = 250.0
sideMenuController.leftViewPresentationStyle = .scaleFromBig

sideMenuController.rightViewWidth = 100.0
sideMenuController.leftViewPresentationStyle = .slideBelow
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is one awesome GitHub library for NavigationDrawer using swift.

To use menu NavigationController, ensure that you indicate UITabBarController or UINavigationController as item content directly, not any corresponding ViewControllers.

```
class NavigationViewController: UINavigationController, SideMenuItemContent {
}

class InnerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: Any) {
        if let navigationViewController = self.navigationController as? SideMenuItemContent {
            navigationViewController.showSideMenu()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is link for 
[sample example](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu/tree/master/Sample) and here is the [main GiHub library](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) link.

I hope this will help you.